# How can I enable Samba 1 authentication for a single share?

Tags: security, samba, authentication

I'm setting up an old network scanner on a debian machine but it uses smb1 for authentication using

```
ntlm auth = yes
```

under the global settings. I know smb1 it's unsecure so I'm guessing if there's the option to use that kind of authentication only for the share I use to receive scans from the machine. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean NTLM v1 authentication (`ntlm auth = yes` alias `ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted`) or SMB protocol v1 (`server min protocol = NT1`)? With a new enough version of Samba, you might need both of these settings.

(Modern defaults e.g. in Debian 11 are `ntlm-auth = ntlmv2-only` and `server min protocol = SMB2_02`.)

Unfortunately both of them are marked with `(G)` in the `smb.conf(5)` man page, indicating that these settings can only be specified in the `[global]` section of the configuration. This is probably because these settings affect the conversation between the client and the server even **before** the client can tell the server which share it wants to access.

Since the weakness of the SMBv1 protocol was the reason why the WannaCry ransomware managed to spread so fast and wide, the attitude towards it among security-aware administrators these days tends to be "**kill SMBv1 with fire**". You might want to e.g. set up a virtual machine, with a stand-alone Samba server dedicated to serving that old scanner and any other SMBv1 devices like that only.

If you want maximum security, you would then have any scanned documents first pass through an anti-virus check before transferring them to a share in another system that will be accessible using SMBv2 or greater, on the assumption that a malicious user might use the scanner's network connection to plug in a malware injector.

Comment: Yes, I mean SMB v1 with NTLM v1 authentication. The virtual machine workaround is is an excellent hint. Thanks!